# Sonar says i have a redundant throw in an interface

Tags: java, interface, sonarqube

I've defined a function in an interface that throws **my own exception**. When I run Sonar it says it a redundant throw. How can I solve this little problem?

This is the definition of the function:

```
OwnBean getOwnBean(Integer code1, String code2) throws OwnBeanException;
```

Thanks for your help!

More info:

I've managed to get more information about this.

The exception is a descendant of other exception that at the end is descendant of `Exception`.

The messagge I get is *"Unable to obtain the information of class OwnBeanException"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say, the most likely explanation is that your OwnBeanException extends RuntimeException, which would explain why it's redundant. RuntimeExceptions (including all classes extending it) are per definition unchecked, declaring them via throws doesn't make sense.

All possibilities, according to the [documentation](http://gazelle.ihe.net/sonar/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3ARedundantThrowsDeclarationCheck%7Cs=createdAt%7Casc=false):

> An exception in a throws declaration in Java is redundant if:
>
> - It is listed multiple times
> - It is a subclass of another listed exception
> - It is a RuntimeException, or one of its descendants

Answer (score 3):

Technically any exception that extends RuntimeException does not have to be declared in *throws-declaration* clause. Therefore throws declaration of it can be considered redundant.

**BUT:**

In Spring-Framework you will see many methods with throws-declarations for exceptions extending RuntimeException.

- Spring avoids checked exceptions.
- For a programmaer using it - it is easier to see what unchecked exceptions can be thrown.

**Example:** org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate class method:

```
@Override
public void delete(URI url) throws RestClientException {
    execute(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, null, null);
}
```

Where:

```
public class RestClientException extends NestedRuntimeException {
    // ...
}
```

Personally I would advocate declaring unchecked exceptions as it is easier for programmers.

Comment: It is not only easier but avoids nasty bugs in production... I stumbled upon this due to the Sonar Cube code smell `"throws" declarations should not be superfluous`